# Rails query to group rows and get the row with the max value in each group

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a table:

```
| id | parent_id | version | other columns ... |
| 1  | 10        | 1       | ...               |
| 2  | 10        | 2       | ...               |
| 3  | 23        | 1       | ...               |
| 4  | 55        | 1       | ...               |
| 5  | 55        | 2       | ...               |
| 6  | 55        | 3       | ...               |
```

I need a Rails query that will

- group by `parent_id`
- identify each group's row with max version value (there won't be dupes)
- return ideally the ActiveRecords, or at least an array of row `id`s

So given the above table, I want a query that will result in rows 2, 3, and 6.

Kinda stunned at how hard this is turning out to be.

Comment: Please also share what you have tried to do.

Comment: It would not be helpful, I assure you.